# Hide pdfs in google search result in .cfm

Tags: pdf, search

Can someone help how can I hide pdfs in google search result, the site is using .cfm pages (coldfusion).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: In some it says that I can do this by adding the following snippet to the site's root .htaccess file or httpd.conf file: but it is using .cfm or coldfusion. Can I use robots.txt on it?

<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>